# Tools for analysis of memory consumed on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, memory-management

we develop web application, some of our applications seems much memory consumption on the client side.

Are there tools to analyze the memory consumption on internet explorer.

We try [iesieve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/) and [drip](http://outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page) but both seems unreliable... we would need more information on what is referencing the elements targeted as leaks.

but it seems very reliable. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [dynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/)?

Comment: @Delan, you talk about drip and iesieve ?

Comment: In your sentence about drip and iesieve, I was wondering if you meant to say 'unreliable' instead of 'reliable'.

Comment: @Pointy We just try it and it's not what we need :-(

Comment: @Delan The problem is that it does not give enough details on what is attached to the DOM. We see that there are references but we are not able to determine which objects are references

Comment: So you did mean to say 'unreliable'?

Answer (score 1):

We tackled an extremely hard to find memory leak in a 3rd party web component using simply Process Explorer from SysInternals and then start dropping components from the web page until the leak stops(and you've found the culprit).

Process Explorer is a simple but extremely robust tool that did the job.

BTW, memory leaks in IE are usually due to circular references or closures.  They are difficult to track down and the best way to isolate them is, as I said, to drop components from the web page until the leak stops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need a tools wich can tell me why i got a memory leak. It's not a big leak, but the memory increase on each page we accessed and we need to know why. Something is not destroyed

Comment: I doubt you can find a tool for IE that can tell you *what* is causing the leak - at least I didn't find one that worked at the time.  What did work was using the process of elimination on each part of the web page.